# Application crash when selecting many rows of a SQLite table

Tags: sql, sqlite, memory, crash

I have a problem with a SQLite database.

I have a table containing 6 million rows.

When I execute `Select * from that_table` I can see in Widows Task Manager that the memory usage increases heavily.
This crashes my application.

I have an administration tool plugin for SQLite in firefox. This tool crashes too when I execute the same query.

Is there a way to select this many rows without crashes?

I guess 6 million rows isn't that much - Shouldn't SQLite be able to handle that?

The application is written in C#. The data is coming from a sensor and is stored in a list of type `ChartObject`. `ChartObject` is a struct of 6 properties:

```
public struct ChartObject
{
    public ISensor Sensor { get; set; }

    public DateTime Category { get; set; }

    public double ValueX { get; set; }

    public double? ValueY { get; set; }

    public double? ValueY2 { get; set; }

    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
}
```

This list contains up to 2 million ChartObjects.
A ChartObject is used to contain 1 measured point, x value, y value, calibrated y value(ValueY2) and the sensor that measured the point.

I use this list to plot data on a graph.

Comment: Depends on the size of each row and what you are doing with the results of the select. Do you need them all in memory at the same time or can you iterate over the rows?

Comment: I need them all in memory at the same time.

Comment: No, sry i use a circular buffer with a limit of 2.000.000. So i never store more than 2 million rows of data in memory.

Comment: That's still potentially a lot of memory depending on the size of the rows. Are you sure you need them in memory? Whatever processing you are doing with them, could you put part of it in the ``select`` so sqlite does some of the work for you and returns a smaller resultset?

Comment: So i would select chunks of data in several select statements?

Comment: Depends. What do you do with the rows once you select them?

Comment: See my edit in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40372/discussion-between-acfrancis-and-user1093774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with sqlite but the way you are using the resultset. If you need to create a new `ChartObject` from each row in the table, iterate over them like this:

```
foreach (var myrow in (from x in that_table select x))
{
    var myChartObject = new ChartObject();
    // populate myChartObject fields from myrow
    // add myChartObject to the actual chart
}
```

If you make the mistake of calling `ToList()` on the Linq query, you will load all those rows into memory unnecessarily. If you don't need the rows in memory at the same time, you can avoid that. Remember that 2 million `ChartObjects` will require a significant amount of memory on their own.